# Excel Formula to Search keyword in a column and return its row number

Tags: excel, formula

I am trying to have excel formula and I don't want to use macro code here.
I want to type in a word in column E4 and I should have a formula in E6 that will search for that word
in the entire column A and return the row number.

For example I type "Grapes" Should give me answer of 4

here is my formula and I am not sure why it is not working, it is working with Grapes but for others it is not

[image]

Here is my formula:
=MATCH(E4,A:A,1)

Comment: `=MATCH("*"&E4&"*",A:A,1)`

Comment: It says N/A not sure why

Comment: sorry should be: `=MATCH("*"&E4&"*",A:A,0)`

Comment: Dude you save my entire life!

Comment: can you put this as an answer so I can grab it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Wildcards (`*`) and look for exact instead of relative:

```
=MATCH("*"&E4&"*",A:A,0)
```

Comment: This saved my entire life! 
30 min for me to get the answer and this is the savior!